# If $x:y = 7:3$ , then find the value of $\frac{y}{x-y}$

Tags: ratio

If $x:y = 7:3$ , then can I in order to find the value of $\frac{y}{x-y}$ replace $x$ and $y$ with $7$ and $3$ respectively ?

Comment: Yes you can do that if you are only concerned with the answer and do not care much about the correctness and rigour of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we have some ratio, multiply it with some variable to find values. So let $x = 7z, y = 3z$.

Thus,

$$ \frac{y}{x-y} = \frac{3z}{7z - 3z} = \frac{3z}{4z}= \frac{3}{4}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac y{x-y}=\frac 1{\frac{x}{y}-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Note that $\frac xy = \frac 73$ gives you that for some $a \in \mathbf R$ we have $x = 7a$ and $y = 3a$, we then have
$$ \frac y{x-y} = \frac{3a}{7a - 3a} = \frac{3}{7-3}= \frac 34. $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What does ratio really mean? $x:y = 7:3$ represents that $x=\frac{7}{3}y$ can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes.. thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

$ \frac{x-y}{y}=\frac{x}{y}-1=\frac{7}{3}-1=\frac{4}{3}$. Hence, what you want $=\frac{3}{4}$